# Unexpected return value from string

Tags: c, function, runtime

I am trying to get just the phone number out of the string passed into **getPhoneNumber(char[] str)**, but for some reason, i get some random character appended to it each time i run the code, please i need help.

**source code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


char* getPhoneNumber(char str[]);

int main(){

  getPhoneNumber("AT+CMGR=5 \n+CMGR: \"REC READ\",\"+9349036332058\",\"samuel\",\"17/03/31,20:44:52+04\"\nHOW THINS fa OK");

  return 0;
}

char* getPhoneNumber(char str[]){

  char *temp = strchr(str, ',')+2;
  const unsigned short len1 = strlen(temp);

  printf("value in temp : %s\n\n",temp);

  char *strPtr = strchr(temp, '\"');
  const unsigned short len2 = strlen(strPtr);

  printf("value in strPtr : %s\n\n",strPtr);
  int phone_num_len = len1-len2;

  char phone_num[phone_num_len];

  strncpy(phone_num, temp,phone_num_len);

  printf("Phone number : %s",phone_num);

}
```

I also printed out individual values of **temp** and **strPtr** for debugging purposes, but the returned values seems ok.
The output of the program is shown in the image below.

[image]

Comment: `strncpy()` despite its name was not designed to work with *strings*. It does not care about the terminating `'\0'` mandatory for *strings*. You should add that`'\0'` byte yourself after the call, or use another function. Also you need to account for that terminating byte when calculating the size of the result array.

Comment: but when i try running it on [ideone](http://ideone.com/FOQi4V) i get the expected output.

Comment: Post text as text is preferred over posting text as a picture.

Comment: @lilfancy so there *happened* to be a terminating 0 conveniently there.

Comment: well noted @chux

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not setting aside enough space for `phone_num`.  As a result, `printf` is reading past the end of the array.  This invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  That is why you see extra characters when running locally but it appears to work fine on ideone (it also appears to run fine for me).

You need one more byte for the null terminating character for the string.  Also, you need to manually add that null terminator since the `strncpy` function won't do it for you since there's no null terminator within `phone_num_len` bytes of `temp`.

```
char phone_num[phone_num_len+1];

strncpy(phone_num, temp,phone_num_len);
phone_num[phone_num_len] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 1):

From the man page for `strncpy(char * dst, const char * src, size_t len)`:

> If src is less than len characters long, the remainder of dst is filled with `\0' characters.  Otherwise, dst is not terminated.

So it is not, as you seem to expect, terminating the "string" you are copying.